# Не могу получить id get запроса в golang

Tags: golang

Написал следующий код:

routers.go

```
...
    r.HandleFunc("/api/user/{id}", controllers.APIGetUser).Methods("GET")
...
```

В функции APIGetUser пытаюсь получить значение id следующий образом:

```
func APIGetUser(w http.ResponseWriter, r *http.Request) {
params, found := mux.Vars(r)["id"]
    if !found {
        log.Println(": [INFO] Id not found ")
    }
    var user models.Users
    db.Find(&user, params)
    json.NewEncoder(w).Encode(user)
}
```

Но при запросе вида ../api/user/1 в лог пишет "ID not found", т.е. id по какой-то причине не найден. Через отладку смотрел значение переменой params, всегда mux.Vars(r)["id"] возвращает пустое значение - "".

В чём может быть проблема, так как поискав информацию, везде указывают такой метод получения параметра get запроса.

Comment: Попробовал сделать запрос через postman (http://127.0.0.1:8000/user/34), все работает. Можно посмотреть код из метода настройки роутера?

Comment: В main.go вызываю функцию `http.Handle("/", routers.Handlers())  
 log.Fatal(http.ListenAndServe(":"+port, handlers.LoggingHandler(os.Stdout, routers.Handlers())))`. Далее в routers.go `func Handlers() *mux.Router {
 static := http.StripPrefix("/static/", http.FileServer(http.Dir("./static/")))
 r := mux.NewRouter()
        r.HandleFunc("/api/user/{id}", controllers.APIGetUser).Methods("GET")
 return r
}`.